# Отправка куки на сервер

Tags: javascript, cookie, axios, fetch

Есть Vue приложение. С него идёт запрос к API для получения данных о пользователе. Для получения этих данных мне нужно отправить cookie с запросом, но не выходит.

Fetch: ( в credentials ставил и same-origin и include )

[image]

Axios: ( если axios'у задаю заголовок `Cookie`, то он выплёвывает ошибку `Refused to set unsafe header`. Все предложенные варианты делал, ничего не менялось )

[image]

Сами куки: ( отправляю вторые куки )

[image]

Если потребуется ещё какая-та информация - пишите, добавлю.

Конфиг сервера:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://pwa.domain.ru"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cookie"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS, ACTION"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Comment: Если вы хотите подменить содержимое заголовка cookie, то редактируйте window.document.cookie вместо всего этого

Comment: @andreymal тут больше проблема в том, что куки просто не шлются. Ни в каком виде